# Make 'b' the subject in the quadratic formula

Tags: mathematics

[image]

Solve for b in terms of a,x and c in the fastest way possible.

Comment: "subject" is a somewhat vague term. What you're presumably asking for is known in math as "isolating" or "solving for". "fastest" is also ambiguous. Do you mean "fewest operations"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the quadratic equation

> we can go back to the original equation
>  $$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $$
>  and solve it for $b$, which yields:
>  $$ b = - \frac{ax^2 + c}{x} $$

Comment: Wow, I know mathematics university graduates who couldn't crack that one out. I love this exchange. Speaking of which. How do the tickings work for people giving out questions with both 1 answer, and an answer the OP knows?

Comment: If you know an even faster way, then wait some time, so that people have a chance to come up with it on their own.

Comment: And since this is the fastest way I know of?

Comment: @yolo Then you may tick it as soon as you want. But I fear that this question is not 'puzzling' enough and might get closed. But you could also wait whether someone comes up with a more puzzling-like solution.

Comment: A.P I think the firsy sentence in your answer is a bit of a giveaway...

Comment: @yolo Good point. I hid it a little bit better now.

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest... I kind of assumed we had to pretend we didn't already know the answer.

Multiply by 2a

> $$2ax=-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

Square everything

> $$2ax*2ax=b^2+b^2-4ac \pm 2b\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

Simplify

> $$4a^2x^2=-4ac-2b(-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac})$$

Hey that looks familiar

> $$4a^2x^2=-4ac-4bax$$

Finish it up

> $$b=-\frac{ax^2+c}{x}$$

Comment: 'we had to pretend we didn't already know the answer'- how so? I've never known anyone who knows the formula for b as general knowledge.

Comment: ax^2+bx+c=0 is common knowledge and pretty much is solved. That answer is correct; i think this adds to the discussion but is not fast enough.